# Stack Overflow error caused by defining variable?

Tags: java, android, stack-overflow

I know what a stack overflow error is, but I just don't see how I have caused one with my code.  I'm getting the error immediately after I run the program, and it doesn't point to any sort of recursion, but rather a variable definition.  I've looked at a lot of questions concerning this error, but I stil don't see how I caused it.  My code is below, as is my logcat, and I marked where the error occurs.

```
public class DatabaseTable {


    public static final String TAG = "ConstantDatabase";

    //the columns included in the table
    public static final String COL_QUANTITY = "QUANTITY";
    public static final String COL_VALUE = "VALUE";
    public static final String COL_UNCERTAINTY = "UNCERTAINTY";
    public static final String COL_UNIT = "UNIT";
    public static final String _id = "_id";
//name, tbale name, version
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CONSTANTS";
    private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "FTS";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    private final DatabaseOpenHelper mDatabaseOpenHelper;
    private final Context mcontext;





    public DatabaseTable(Context context){
        mDatabaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
        mcontext = context;

    }

    private  class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private final Context mHelperContext = mcontext;


        private final DatabaseOpenHelper hDatabaseOpenHelper =  new DatabaseOpenHelper(mHelperContext);
// Stack Overflow error here ^
        private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
        private final MyDataProvider dp = new MyDataProvider(mcontext);


        private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                        " USING fts3 (" +_id+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+
                        COL_QUANTITY + " TEXT, " +
                        COL_VALUE + " TEXT," +
                        COL_UNCERTAINTY + " TEXT," +
                        COL_UNIT + " TEXT " + ")";

        public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            loadConstants();
            Log.e("Database Operation", "DatabaseOpenHelper constructor called, constants loaded?");



        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            mDatabase = db;
            mDatabase.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);
            Log.e("Database Operation", "Constants Table Created ...");
            loadConstants();
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

        public SQLiteDatabase getmDatabase(){
            return mDatabase;
        }


//        populating the virtual table with a string reading code


        private void loadConstants() {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        loadConstantss();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            Log.e("Loading", "Constants Table Populated ...");
        }

        private void loadConstantss() throws IOException {

            HashMap map = dp.getAllMap();

            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ListViewItem>> entries = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while (entries.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, ListViewItem> entry = entries.next();
                Log.d("thing:", entry.getKey());
               addConstant(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getValueS(), entry.getValue().getUncertainty(), entry.getValue().getUnit());

            }




//            final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
//            InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.txt);
//            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
//
//            try {
//                String line;
//                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//                    String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, ",");
//                    if (strings.length < 4) continue;
//                    long id = addConstant(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim(), strings[2].trim(), strings[3].trim());
//                    if (id < 0) {
//                        Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
//                    }
//                }
//            } finally {
//                reader.close();
//            }
        }

        public long addConstant(String quantity, String value, String uncertainty, String unit) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = hDatabaseOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();


            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(COL_QUANTITY, quantity);
            initialValues.put(COL_VALUE, value);
            initialValues.put(COL_UNCERTAINTY, uncertainty);
            initialValues.put(COL_UNIT, unit);


            db.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
            return db.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }


        //database openhelper ends

    }




    public Cursor getWordMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
        String selection = COL_QUANTITY + " MATCH ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};


        return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
    }


    public Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);

        Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
                columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    //get all titles
    public Cursor getAllTitles()
    {
        return mDatabaseOpenHelper.getmDatabase().query(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, new String[] {
                        COL_QUANTITY,
                        COL_UNCERTAINTY,
                        COL_UNIT,
                        COL_VALUE},
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);
    }


}
```

Logcat:

```
07-07 10:11:42.947 14069-14069/com.gmd.referenceapplication D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.<init>(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:77)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:0)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
     at com.gmd.referenceapplication.DatabaseTable$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseTable.java:61)
07-07 10:11:42.949 14069-14069/com.gmd.referenceapplication D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 20092852
07-07 10:11:42.949 14069-14069/com.gmd.referenceapplication E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 20092936)
07-07 10:11:42.950 14069-14069/com.gmd.referenceapplication E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
          android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 20092936 bytes
              at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
              at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
              at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4425)
              at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:90)
              at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
              at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
07-07 10:11:42.950 14069-14069/com.gmd.referenceapplication I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14069 SIG: 9
```

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Your DatabaseOpenHelper has a DatabaseOpenHelper field, one you initialize on creation!

Comment: And the problem is not due to "defining" a variable, but rather due to initializing an object of a certain type within its own creation code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you create a `DatabaseOpenHelper` in each `DatabaseOpenHelper` is your problem:

```
private  class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final DatabaseOpenHelper hDatabaseOpenHelper =  new DatabaseOpenHelper(mHelperContext); //this line is your problem

....
}
```

This initializer gets executed in the constructor, which executes the constructor etc...